# Does Ruby bundler support shallow git cloning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

How can one refer to Gem dependencies stored at a Git URL without cloning the entire repository in order to make the fetching as efficient as possible?

After searching, I found a bug trail to https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/4475 and [no documentation upon https://bundler.io/](https://bundler.io/guides/git.html) about `depth 1`.

I want to switch an existing Rails pipeline to using git sources as I want to avoid Gem artifacts and Gem stores since [Gitlab package registry does not support Gems](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/rubygems_registry/).

My dependencies might have large git repositories, so I am looking to make this as efficient as possible.

Comment: I'm confused too, because I don't know what you're confused about. Just saying *I'm confused* isn't very useful.

Comment: Same question gets 10 upvotes on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/11gn4ua/can_bundler_do_shallow_git_clones_like_go/

Comment: Congrats, you've determined that Reddit has far lower moderation standards. SO isn't meant to be a site where you can half-ass questions with vague, meaningless words. The best advice I can give to *anyone* wanting to ask questions on SO is that *this site is not about you.* This site is about *the people that will come after you.* If your question only has use *for you* and will not be meaningfully searchable and useful to the people that come *after you* then you should not expect your question to survive, because the moderation tools are precisely tuned to excise that garbage. (as shown)

Comment: You were even given a *very low bar* of adding detail to your question to make it meaningful. You could have very easily come back to this question and updated it to provide detail on what was confusing, what your expectations were, and why they were not met. You know, the very basic stuff explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and expected of **every** question, but rather than make a meaningful contribution to your own question you spent that time on Reddit and complaining in the comments here. Not a surprise at all that your question was closed.